# Why is the character movment for my game not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

My character movement is bugging and i don't know why at all
When i run it it moves forward and like bugs backwards
Ive changed velocity and framerate to no avail and an scared to touch the code coz i just got it to work when  the backgound is visible

```py
import pygame
import os

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1920, 1080
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Gaem")
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
FPS = 60
Vel = 5
CHARACTER = pygame.image.load('MAN.png')
def draw_window(CHARACTERM):
    WIN.fill((WHITE))
    WIN.blit(CHARACTER, (CHARACTERM.x, CHARACTERM.y))
    
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    CHARACTERM = pygame.Rect(100, 300, 850, 450)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False


##########CHARACTER MOVMENT####################
        draw_window(CHARACTERM)
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a]: #Left
            CHARACTERM.x -= Vel


        draw_window(CHARACTERM)
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d]: #Right
            CHARACTERM.x += Vel


        draw_window(CHARACTERM)
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w]: #Up
            CHARACTERM.y -= Vel


        draw_window(CHARACTERM)
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s]: #Down
            CHARACTERM.y += Vel

################################################
        draw_window(CHARACTERM)
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thank you Zatando1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to call `pygame.key.get_pressed()` and `draw_window()` once:

```py
def main():
    CHARACTERM = pygame.Rect(100, 300, 850, 450)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a]: #Left
            CHARACTERM.x -= Vel
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d]: #Right
            CHARACTERM.x += Vel
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w]: #Up
            CHARACTERM.y -= Vel
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s]: #Down
            CHARACTERM.y += Vel

        draw_window(CHARACTERM)
    pygame.quit()
```

If you call `draw_window()` multiple times, [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) will be executed multiple times in each frame. An update of the display at the end of the application loop is sufficient. Multiple calls to `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` cause flickering.